# Justify text on textbox for access 2016 reports

Tags: ms-access, vba

Im trying to justify my text boxes for a report on Access 2016. I found this http://www.lebans.com/justidirect.htm control activex, but Access 2016, seems not to open it since is too old version of Access file (mdb).
Is there a way around to be able to JUSTIFY text on Access reports, AND simultaniously, have the property can grow/ can shrink¨on text boxes?Like some kind of property that can be coded on VBA?
Suggestions?

Pia

Answer (score 0):

I converted the old Access 2000 "Class justidirectver17.mdb" with Access 2010 to .accdb format. You can download a .7z of it here:

https://mega.nz/#!x1ZXkA4D!p2IYZbCEcCg0q1UrdXwNaebRWHl6ZYnBs4lgU22O54o

(be sure to pick "Download via browser")

Actually it's not an ActiveX control, but a pure VBA solution, which should help with portability.